# Which is the right phrase?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I came across a line "Once you decide to apply, make sure your CV is short, make sense and is without ___ of any kind". Is it "errors" or "an error" and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you meant to write "...makes sense...". As to your substantive question you **can** say "..without error...". That is analogous to using the singular of nouns with 'none' or 'no', as in the Lord Chancellor's song that begins:

"The Law is the true embodiment
of everything that's excellent.
It has no kind of fault or flaw"

But that was written in the 19th century. These days most native speakers would use the plural: "errors".